# Add data to Observable

Tags: rxjs, rxjs5

I have three Observables that are containing fetched data from the server (all of the same type). For displaying the data nicely I want to add empty data points to the streams so the times align (the time of the recording of the data). Something like this:

```
Stream 1: 12:30 ------ 15:30 -- 16:00 ----------------- 19:00
Stream 2: 12:30 --------------- 16:00 ------ 17:30 ----------
Stream 3: -------------15:30 -------------------------- 19:00
                    |                            |
                    V                            V
Stream 1: 12:30 ------ 15:30 -- 16:00 ------(17:30)---- 19:00
Stream 2: 12:30 ------(15:30)-- 16:00 ------ 17:30 ----(19:00)
Stream 3:(12:30)-------15:30 --(16:00)------(17:30)---- 19:00
```

Parenthesis mean empty.
Is there a good way to do this? Or do I have to change it completely?

Comment: Maybe you need smth like `merge` `concat`?

Answer (score 1):

[`combineLatest`](http://rxmarbles.com/#combineLatest) would be helpful here if you need to combine all 3 streams into 1. If you need 3 output streams, go with [`withLatestFrom`](http://rxmarbles.com/#withLatestFrom) or [`sample`](http://rxmarbles.com/#sample). `withLatestFrom` allows you to write a selector function that combines both source, `sample` directly output the original value. Notice you have to reverse the parameters on `withLatestFrom` compared to sample.

You probably also want the new stream to emit just 1 value when 2 of the sources emit in very close succession. We can do this with [`debounce`](http://rxmarbles.com/#debounce).

The code for `combineLatest` is really straight forwards:

```
Rx.Observable.combineLatest(source1, source2, source3, (s1, s2, s3) => ...)
  .debounce(10)
```

Result in:

```
Stream 1: 12:30 ------ 15:30 -- 16:00 ----------------- 19:00
Stream 2: 12:30 --------------- 16:00 ------ 17:30 ----------
Stream 3: -------------15:30 -------------------------- 19:00
                    |                            |
                    V                            V
Stream:   12:30 ------ 15:30 -- 16:00 -------17:30----- 19:00
```

If we want 3 streams, we use `withLatestFrom`:

```
var streams = Rx.Observable.merge(source1, source2, source3);
s1 = source1.sample(sources).debounce(10);
s2 = source2.sample(sources).debounce(10);
s3 = stream3.sample(sources).debounce(10);
```

or if we use `withLatestFrom`:

```
s1 = streams.withLatestFrom(source1).debounce(10);
```

Result in:

```
Stream 1: 12:30 ------ 15:30 -- 16:00 ----------------- 19:00
Stream 2: 12:30 --------------- 16:00 ------ 17:30 ----------
Stream 3: -------------15:30 -------------------------- 19:00
                    |                            |
                    V                            V
Stream 1: 12:30 ------ 15:30 -- 16:00 ------ 16:00 ---- 19:00
Stream 2: 12:30 -------12:30 -- 16:00 ------ 17:30 ---- 17:30
Stream 3: -------------15:30 -- 15:30 ------ 15:30 ---- 19:00
```

I'm not 100% sure what you mean with "Parenthesis mean empty". Did you want a marble like this?

```
Stream 1: a ---- b ------------ c --------- d ---------
Stream 2: g ---- i -----k------ l --------- m ---------
Stream 3: h ---- j ------------ i ----u---- a ---------
                    |                            |
                    V                            V
Stream 1: a ---- b -----_------ c ----_---- d ---------
Stream 2: g ---- i -----k------ l ----_---- m ---------
Stream 3: h ---- j -----_------ i ----u---- a ---------
```

Where `_` is an empty element?

```
source1.sample(Rx.Observable.merge(source1, source2, source3))
  .debounce(10)
  .startWith("_")
  .publish(xs => xs.zip(xs.skip(1)), (a, b) => a === b ? "_", b)
```

We can then use `sample`, but filter duplicate values and replace them with an empty element. To do so, we use a little trick where we compare the last 2 elements, if they are equal, we insert an empty value.

Comment: Basicly I mean that what your last marbe diagram shows, but with the dates. The dates are part of a model. Instead of underscores the empty model should contain the date and a few default values. My function would look like this: [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/jHZfT4ww)

Comment: I like to add, that the default value is delivered through a function that takes a key and outputs a default value. In my example that key is a timecode and the resulting default value is a model with the needed default values and the date.

Comment: @SuperManitu My current answer is a bit sloppy, i replaced `withLatestFrom` with `sample` when i realized `sample` was a nice alternative, but i think i made a few mistakes there. I'll clean it up later.

Comment: @SuperManitu As for your question. I think something like `Rx.Observable.merge(source1, source2, source3).scan(/* select max time */).debounce(1).withLatestFrom(CurrentSource, (time, current) => /* combine them */).publish(xs => xs.zip(xs.skip(1)), (a, b) => a.value === b.value ? "_", b)` will work.

Comment: That's assuming there is at least 1 ms (or to be safe, 15ms) between values on the sources, but if 2 streams yield, they do so in a a ms timespan. And also that we can filter duplicates by comparing values, I.E. the sources will not yield the same value twice normally. (If that's a problem, we can still modify to source to guard against that)

Comment: dont understand your code, can you explain it? I tried to do my method here: http://pastebin.com/UY2G2Nzf , but I was not able to make it work

Comment: @SuperManitu Haven't had much time to look at your code earlier, but what i extract from it, is that you merely want to insert default values if a stream had no activity for 1,5 hours. Then you want to insert a default value. So correct me if i'm wrong, but: The default value and the timeout is based on the latest item from the current stream, and is unrelated to the other streams.

Comment: The code has nothing to do with timeouts. I have a few streams of models that I gather by merging ajax streams with self written websocket streams, so they are hot observable. The models consists of a few values and a date. Whenever one of the streams emits a value and the others dont, the others should emit a default value based on the timestamp of the emitted value